# How to populate model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i send GET request to my orders, response return me OjectID in my orderItems. How can i populate model to get orderItems name in my case? My Order items related to Product Model. Need to return product name. I am a newer in mongo db. Dont well understand populate method in Mongo

Postman result

```
[
    {
        "orderItems": [
            "60668d8514508746c5480ede"
        ],
        "status": "3",
        "_id": "60668d8514508746c5480edf",
        "shippingAddress1": "Lo",
        "shippingAddress2": "2/1",
        "city": "5",
        "zip": "5",
        "phone": "5633",
        "totalPrice": 700,
        "user": {
            "_id": "60644f8d87463d10b8c7bb27",
            "name": "Lopez",
            "id": "60644f8d87463d10b8c7bb27"
        },
        "dateOrdered": "2021-04-02T03:20:37.884Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "60668d8514508746c5480edf"
    }
]
```

My get request

```
router.get(`/`, async (req, res) =>{
    const orderList = await Order.find().populate('user', 'name').sort({'dateOrdered': -1});

    if(!orderList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(orderList);
})
```

Models

```
// Order Model
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderItems: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'OrderItem',
        required:true
    }],
orderSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

orderSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

//Order Items Model

onst orderItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }
})

exports.OrderItem = mongoose.model('OrderItem', orderItemSchema);
```

Comment: I tryed your code, nothing changed, returned object ID. Product not populated

Comment: Try `Order.find().populate('user', 'name').populate('orderItems')` .

Comment: Did you get orderItems populated ?

Answer (score 1):

> Order -> orderItems -> product

**Option -1**

```
Order.find().populate('user', 'name').populate({ path : 'orderItems', populate : { path : 'product' } })
```

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1377

---

**Option -2**

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-middleware

Add this:-

```
const populateProduct = function(next) {
  this.populate('product');
  next();
};

orderItemSchema.pre('findOne', populateProduct).pre('find', populateProduct);
```

---

Change query like:-

```
Order.find().populate('user', 'name').populate('orderItems')
```

---

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate

Comment: Gupta, thank you, but in orders list view doesnt work. mongoose-autopopulate, think it may be a good solution in my case. Thanks